# My node.js gives me error and I dont understand what's the problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, node-modules

This is the error please help me. I tried to npm install @discord-api-types/v9 but nothing changed. I am trying to create a discord bot but when I type node index.js to terminal it keeps giving me error.

````
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@discord-api-types/v9'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\Rayman Music\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\Rayman Music\index.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\MONSTER\\Desktop\\Rayman Music\\index.js' ]
}```
````

Comment: did you check package.json? is that module installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error means it can't find either a package or a file, in this case a package.

Ensure you have the package [discord-api-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-api-types) by doing

```
npm install discord-api-types
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to npm version.

In old versions, you need to write a flag in command to add the module to dependencies.

```
npm install <module> --save
```

Check version, but first check whether that module has been added to dependencies after executing npm install command without flag in package.json file